# Download images from google drive

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, wget, download-manager

I have multiple google drive images url in the text file, I want to download each image from its url, Here catch is I want to download and save images to it's original name.
Here is the reference
[image]

Can anyone help me with the solution

***Alternate Solution***:
I have found out one solution to make it download images

Original URL:-
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwJzkr_gZEA0d1h2dTN6MndvdkE

Convert it to:-
https://drive.google.com/**uc?export=download**&id=0BwJzkr_gZEA0d1h2dTN6MndvdkE

After that add this url into IDM you will able to download image with original name.

Hope that will help.

Comment: You need to show us some code that you have written. Here's a [guide](http://kirankoduru.github.io/software-engineering/ask-better-questions-on-stackoverflow.html) to asking better questions that get answered.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to do it throught Google Drive API : 
[here to create a simple script](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) and [here for endpoints](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html)